# Running Spring Boot without database fails

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, no-database

Im trying to configure a project without database and fails with the next error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/embedded/EmbeddedDatabaseType
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.<clinit>(EmbeddedDatabaseConnection.java:49) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties.<init>(DataSourceProperties.java:155) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.10.RELEASE.jar:1.5.10.RELEASE]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:142) ~[spring-beans-4.3.14.RELEASE.jar:4.3.14.RELEASE]
... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
... 26 common frames omitted
```

In my SpringBootApplication class I have the next configuration:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class})
public class MySpringBootApplication  {
```

It doesn't make sense because is like trying to read a DataSourceProperties class in a No Database application.

I'm using gradle with the next dependencies:

```
compile "io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:${swaggerVersion}",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator",
        "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-config",
        "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web",
      //"org.springframework:spring-jdbc",
        "io.fabric8:spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes:${springCloudKubernetes}",
        "ma.glasnost.orika:orika-core:${orikaVersion}",
        'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.20'

testCompile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test",
        'com.github.sbrannen:spring-test-junit5:1.0.2',
        'org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.0.0',

        "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}"
testRuntime "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}",
        "org.junit.platform:junit-platform-launcher:1.0.2"

testAgent("org.jacoco:org.jacoco.agent:${jacocoVersion}:runtime")
```

If I add the "org.springframework:spring-jdbc" works but doesn't make sense for me to add a database lib for a no database project.

Any idea or clue?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you don't have `spring-data-starter` then maybe it's spring cloud who is the suspect, maybe you should `exclude` something from it

Comment: It looks lihe one who have this class is org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure but this one is included transitively by all the dependencies in my list

Comment: can you share your full dependencies section in build.gradle file?

Comment: Yes, edited @jcrada

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem (*using Spring-Boot 2.0.0.RELEASE*): I have a Spring-Boot-package without a database. It solely serves static files.

In order to make it work (and not crash during database auto-configuration), **I replaced the annotation @SpringBootApplication with** the following two:

```
@SpringBootConfiguration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
```

This made the server start without a JPA-/JDBC-dependency and without any database-related configuration property inside the application.properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Just try your shared dependency and I everything looks ok (application start with not issue), as expected there is not need to `@EnableAutoConfiguration` for excluding DataSourceAutoConfiguration as you do not have a DataSource class in the path (at least with those dependencies). So I believe

1. You have problem refreshing dependencies in your system/IDE, try `gradle clean build`
2. You are using wrong dependency combinations spring-cloud-starter-config for example `2.0.0.M6` with spring boot `1.5.x`
3. You have another dependency adding `DataSource` class to class path.
4. You have in your resource file of resource server data source configuration properties.